# Scala Type Mismatch For Subclasses of The Same Parent

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spray

UserGetResponse and GeneralResponse are sublclasses of BaseResponse, which is as follows:

```
abstract class BaseResponse()
```

And the function I use to retrieve users is as follows:

```
  def userGet(userId: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[BaseResponse] = Future {
    val response = users.get(userId) map { user =>
        val userRes = new UserResponse(user.id, user.firstname, user.lastname, user.organisationid, user.email, user.password, user.usertype)
        new UserGetResponse(1, "Successful retrieved the user.", userRes)
    } getOrElse {
      GeneralResponse(0, s"Error retrieving user. User does not exist.")
    }
  }
```

where users is another class with methods get, insert etc. defined. I am getting the following compilation error:

```
 type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: package.name.BaseResponse
[error]   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closure inside the `Future` is not returning anything, so the compiler infers that it's return type is `Unit`, and complains because it should be `BaseResponse`.

Removing `val response =` from the beginning of the function (or adding `response` before the end) should fix it.

Comment: yes, or just put `response` at the end of the function